# How to find repeating sequence of Integers in an array of Integers in java?

Tags: java, arrays

For example if input is:

> 2 0 6 3 1 6 3 1 6 3 1

then output should be 6 3 1.Need to find the first repetition cycle.

```
class FindDuplicate
{
void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i; 
    System.out.println("The repeating elements are : ");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[Math.abs(arr[i])] >= 0)
            arr[Math.abs(arr[i])] = -arr[Math.abs(arr[i])];
        else
            System.out.print(Math.abs(arr[i]) + " ");
    }        
} 


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    FindDuplicate duplicate = new FindDuplicate();
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
    int arr_size = arr.length;
    duplicate.printRepeating(arr, arr_size);
}
}
```

Comment: add some code if you want to get help from this site

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow. Show your effort and a specific problem. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please don't post code as a comment. As you can see, it's completely unreadable. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44392764/edit) and [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Did you read the links I included in my previous comment?

Comment: I have attached it. I am getting 1 2 3 1 as output instead of 1 2 3

Comment: @AkshayArora Screenshots aren't any better. We can't copy and paste that code into our own editor so we can run and see for ourselves. You clearly have not read any of the links I've included in my comments. Please go back and read them so that your question is answerable.

Comment: Cant you rather copy and paste your code into the question? Then the rest of us can run it in our own ide's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class FindDuplicate {
    static int STRING_LENGTH = 3;

    void printRepeating(int arr[], int size) {
        int i; 
        System.out.println("The repeating elements are : ");
        String strVal = "";
        for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++) {
            strVal += arr[ii]; 
        }
        // strVal now has something we can search with.

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int end = Math.min(size,i+STRING_LENGTH );
            String searchString = strVal.substring(i, end);
            if (searchString.length() != STRING_LENGTH)
                break;  // at end of arr, doesn't have length to search 
            int matchIndex = strVal.indexOf(searchString, i+1);
            if (matchIndex != -1) {
               String match = strVal.substring(matchIndex, matchIndex + STRING_LENGTH);
               System.out.print(match + " ");
               break; // done with loop
            }
        }        
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FindDuplicate duplicate = new FindDuplicate();
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
        int arr_size = arr.length;
        duplicate.printRepeating(arr, arr_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not limiting, still getting 1 2 3 1 2 3 instead of only 1 2 3

Comment: Then put a break after the 1st print.

Answer (score 1):

https://pastebin.com/12bnjzfw
Have used java 8 streams for collection creation.

```
for (int seqSize = ints.size() / 2; seqSize > 0; seqSize--) { //It should be first cycle. Main priority is biggest sequence
  for (int i = 0; i < ints.size() / seqSize; i++) { //Start position of the first block
    for (int j = i + seqSize; j < ints.size() - seqSize + 1; j++) {
      if (ints.subList(i, i + seqSize).equals(ints.subList(j, j + seqSize))) {
        System.out.println("Answer is: " + ints.subList(i, i + seqSize));
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly for me in my case the pattern will always start at fist character and needs to fill the whole string. But nice usage of java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through those array elements and cache your elements until you have the same value for example

```
List list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
if(list.contains(element))
 //code to check here
```

you will need get size of your list and based on that check exactly this amount of items if they match if yes then output if not clear cache and start cache from the begging.